# Trying to swap shipfromlocationref to shiptolocationref for the below XML and facing namespace issue

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to swap two of the values in my XML below, In my below xml ShipFromLocationRef has value RO91 and ShipToLocationRef has value 6449706. My requirement is to swap R091 to ShipToLocationRef and 6449706 to ShipFromLocationRef.

Requesting you to please help here Below is my XML what i want to get transformed

```
<otm:Release xmlns:otm="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm/transmission/v6.4" xmlns:gtm="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/gtm/transmission/v6.4">
<otm:ReleaseGid>
<otm:Gid>
<otm:DomainName>M02</otm:DomainName>
<otm:Xid>OR_DEL_REJ_8</otm:Xid>
</otm:Gid>
</otm:ReleaseGid>
<otm:TransactionCode>IU</otm:TransactionCode>
<otm:ReleaseHeader>
<otm:ReleaseMethodGid>
<otm:Gid>
<otm:DomainName>M02</otm:DomainName>
<otm:Xid>MEU_OC_LINE</otm:Xid>
</otm:Gid>
</otm:ReleaseMethodGid>
<otm:FlexFieldStrings>
<otm:Attribute1>SO</otm:Attribute1>
<otm:Attribute4>10</otm:Attribute4>
<otm:Attribute5/>
<otm:Attribute6/>
<otm:Attribute7/>
<otm:Attribute8/>
<otm:Attribute10/>
<otm:Attribute11/>
<otm:Attribute13/>
<otm:Attribute14/>
<otm:Attribute15/>
<otm:Attribute16>07</otm:Attribute16>
</otm:FlexFieldStrings>
<otm:FlexFieldNumbers>
<otm:AttributeNumber1>6</otm:AttributeNumber1>
<otm:AttributeNumber2>6</otm:AttributeNumber2>
</otm:FlexFieldNumbers>
<otm:FlexFieldDates>
<otm:AttributeDate1>
<otm:GLogDate>20190904080000</otm:GLogDate>
<otm:TZId/>
<otm:TZOffset/>
</otm:AttributeDate1>
</otm:FlexFieldDates>
</otm:ReleaseHeader>
<otm:ShipFromLocationRef>
<otm:LocationRef>
<otm:LocationGid>
<otm:Gid>
<otm:DomainName>M02</otm:DomainName>
<otm:Xid>6521926</otm:Xid>
</otm:Gid>
</otm:LocationGid>
</otm:LocationRef>
</otm:ShipFromLocationRef>
<otm:ShipToLocationRef>
<otm:LocationRef>
<otm:LocationGid>
<otm:Gid>
<otm:DomainName>M02</otm:DomainName>
<otm:Xid>LT91</otm:Xid>
</otm:Gid>
</otm:LocationGid>
</otm:LocationRef>
</otm:ShipToLocationRef>
<otm:TimeWindow>
<otm:EarlyPickupDt>
<otm:GLogDate>20190904080000</otm:GLogDate>
</otm:EarlyPickupDt>
</otm:TimeWindow>
<otm:ReleaseLine>
<otm:ReleaseLineGid>
<otm:Gid>
<otm:DomainName>M02</otm:DomainName>
</otm:Gid>
</otm:ReleaseLineGid>
<otm:PackagedItemRef>
<otm:PackagedItem>
<otm:Packaging>
<otm:PackagedItemGid>
<otm:Gid>
<otm:DomainName>M02</otm:DomainName>
<otm:Xid>4041392</otm:Xid>
</otm:Gid>
</otm:PackagedItemGid>
</otm:Packaging>
<otm:Item>
<otm:TransactionCode>IU</otm:TransactionCode>
<otm:ItemGid>
<otm:Gid>
<otm:DomainName>M02</otm:DomainName>
<otm:Xid>4041392</otm:Xid>
</otm:Gid>
</otm:ItemGid>
</otm:Item>
</otm:PackagedItem>
</otm:PackagedItemRef>
<otm:ItemQuantity>
<otm:ItemTag1/>
<otm:ItemTag2/>
<otm:WeightVolume>
<otm:Weight>
<otm:WeightValue>2312.35</otm:WeightValue>
<otm:WeightUOMGid>
<otm:Gid>
<otm:Xid>KG</otm:Xid>
</otm:Gid>
</otm:WeightUOMGid>
</otm:Weight>
<otm:Volume>
<otm:VolumeValue>3.74</otm:VolumeValue>
<otm:VolumeUOMGid>
<otm:Gid>
<otm:Xid>CUMTR</otm:Xid>
</otm:Gid>
</otm:VolumeUOMGid>
</otm:Volume>
</otm:WeightVolume>
<otm:PackagedItemCount>7</otm:PackagedItemCount>
</otm:ItemQuantity>
</otm:ReleaseLine>
<otm:ReleaseRefnum>
<otm:ReleaseRefnumQualifierGid>
<otm:Gid>
<otm:DomainName>M02</otm:DomainName>
<otm:Xid>DELIVERY_NOTE_NUMBER</otm:Xid>
</otm:Gid>
</otm:ReleaseRefnumQualifierGid>
<otm:ReleaseRefnumValue>M02.3708030153</otm:ReleaseRefnumValue>
</otm:ReleaseRefnum>
<otm:ReleaseRefnum>
<otm:ReleaseRefnumQualifierGid>
<otm:Gid>
<otm:DomainName>M02</otm:DomainName>
<otm:Xid>ENTRY_MODE</otm:Xid>
</otm:Gid>
</otm:ReleaseRefnumQualifierGid>
<otm:ReleaseRefnumValue>FLATTO</otm:ReleaseRefnumValue>
</otm:ReleaseRefnum>
<otm:Remark>
<otm:RemarkQualifierGid>
<otm:Gid>
<otm:DomainName>M02</otm:DomainName>
<otm:Xid>LOGGED_USER</otm:Xid>
</otm:Gid>
</otm:RemarkQualifierGid>
<otm:RemarkText>M02.FLATTO</otm:RemarkText>
</otm:Remark>
<otm:InvolvedParty>
<otm:TransactionCode>IU</otm:TransactionCode>
<otm:InvolvedPartyQualifierGid>
<otm:Gid>
<otm:DomainName>M02</otm:DomainName>
<otm:Xid>PRINCIPAL_PAYER</otm:Xid>
</otm:Gid>
</otm:InvolvedPartyQualifierGid>
<otm:InvolvedPartyLocationRef>
<otm:LocationRef>
<otm:LocationGid>
<otm:Gid>
<otm:DomainName>M02</otm:DomainName>
<otm:Xid>LT21</otm:Xid>
</otm:Gid>
</otm:LocationGid>
</otm:LocationRef>
</otm:InvolvedPartyLocationRef>
<otm:ContactRef>
<otm:Contact>
<otm:ContactGid>
<otm:Gid>
<otm:DomainName>M02</otm:DomainName>
<otm:Xid>LT21</otm:Xid>
</otm:Gid>
</otm:ContactGid>
<otm:TransactionCode>IU</otm:TransactionCode>
<otm:LocationGid>
<otm:Gid>
<otm:DomainName>M02</otm:DomainName>
<otm:Xid>LT21</otm:Xid>
</otm:Gid>
</otm:LocationGid>
</otm:Contact>
</otm:ContactRef>
<otm:ComMethodGid>
<otm:Gid>
<otm:Xid>EMAIL</otm:Xid>
</otm:Gid>
</otm:ComMethodGid>
</otm:InvolvedParty>
</otm:Release>
```

Below is my XSL code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:Transmission="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
            <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
            <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
                            <xsl:copy>
                                            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                            </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Transmission:ShipFromLocationRef/LocationRef/LocationGid/Gid/Xid">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|../Transmission:ShipToLocationRef/LocationRef/LocationGid/Gid/Xid/text()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Transmission:ShipToLocationRef/LocationRef/LocationGid/Gid/Xid">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|../Transmission:ShipFromLocationRef/LocationRef/LocationGid/Gid/Xid/text()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your namespace declaration to match the source's namespace. Instead of:

```
xmlns:Transmission="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
```

use:

```
xmlns:Transmission="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm/transmission/v6.4"
```

---

In addition, you must use the prefix on **every** node in the path that's in the namespace bound to the prefix. Instead of:

```
Transmission:ShipFromLocationRef/LocationRef/LocationGid/Gid/Xid
```

use:

```
Transmission:ShipFromLocationRef/Transmission:LocationRef/Transmission:LocationGid/Transmission:Gid/Transmission:Xid
```

Likewise for all your other paths.